# Write to Google Cloud Storage from Compute Engine PHP

Tags: google-api-php-client

From my Google Compute Engine instances I would like to be able to write files to Google Cloud Storage. Normally, when using the AppEngine, google has it's own PHP StreamWrapper (it's in the AppEngine SDK). However, I do not want to write from AppEngine, but from ComputeEngine.

I tried to get the app engine php sdk working and "fake" an AppEngine context, but this proved to be too much work. I then tried to write my own StreamWrapper based off of Amazon's, but this proved to be a heavy task that I eventually abandoned. It was easier and cheaper (time wise) to just not use Google Storage.

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fpython%2Fphp%2Fsdk%2Fgoogle%2Fappengine%2Fext%2Fcloud_storage_streams%253Fstate%253Dclosed

Amazon has a similar StreamWrapper and it's unfortunate that google doesn't provide one.
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/src/S3/StreamWrapper.php

Does anyone have any ideas on how to better do this? I abandoned writing my own because I just have no experience with streams whatsoever. I've googled for many different things and nothing seems to fit what I'm looking for. Maybe someone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple of ways:

1. Use gsutil utility ([documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install)) and make sure it is installed and authenticated. Then use one of the gsutil commands from command line:

   $cmd="gsutil cp /foo/bar.txt gs://mybucketnamehere";
   shell_exec($cmd);
2. Send the file using this function, I believe I got it from another StackOverflow answer:

   function googStorageURL($bucketName,$file) { 
       $expiry=time()+3600; // One hour authentication
       $accessId='12345678901@developer.gserviceaccount.com';
       $stringPolicy="GET\n\n\n".$expiry."\n/".$bucketName."/".$file;
       $priv_key="123456789012345678901234567890abcdefghi"; //API ACCESS Public Key 
       $pkeyid=openssl_get_privatekey($priv_key);
       if (openssl_sign($stringPolicy,$signature,$pkeyid,'sha256')) {
       $signature=urlencode(base64_encode($signature));
       return 'https://'.$bucketName.'.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/'.$file.'?GoogleAccessId='.$accessId.'&Expires='.$expiry.'&Signature='.$signature; } }

You can get $accessId number (project id) via running this command on SSH:

```
curl "http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google"
```

Or by logging into Developer's Console, navigate to Storage, Cloud Storage, Settings, and looking at the "x-goog-project-id".

I believe that you can also get a private key by going into Settings under Cloud Storage, going to Interoperability tab, Enabling it and Creating a key, then follow the documentation to pass the key in the header. [See More](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/migrating?hl=en_US#keys)